# Simple way to change scrapy .getall() delimiter

Tags: python, scrapy, delimiter

I'm running a basic scrapy crawler and I can't seem to find any documentation within scrapy that allows me to change the delimiter of a `.getall()`. The default appears to be comma separated, but I'm assuming this might cause some errors in data importing elsewhere.

Ideally, I want the exported csv to be comma separated, but the getall() data is pipe or semi-colon separated. I would prefer to fix this efficiently within the scrapy script. For example, say the bit containing the .getall() is

```
def entry_parse(self, response):
    for entry in response.xpath("//tbody[@class='entry-grid-body infinite']//td[@class]"):
        yield {'entry_labels': entry.xpath(".//div[@class='entry-labels']/span/text()").getall()}
```

Ideally, it would be nice to be able pass such an argument into getall() or something similar, but I can't seem to find any documentation allowing that. Any ideas would be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: `getall()` always returns a `list` of strings. if you want the yielded value of the `entry_labels` field to be something other than a list of strings than you will need to do the preprocessing yourself of use an [`ItemLoader`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really a problem of scrapy. Since the `.getall()` method returns a list and the repr of lists have commas by default

```py
>>>repr(["a","b"])
"['a', 'b']"
```

you can use json.dumps and change the delimiter before yielding the item using the `separators`  argument

```py
import json
def entry_parse(self, response):
    for entry in response.xpath("//tbody[@class='entry-grid-body infinite']//td[@class]"):
        yield {
            'entry_labels': json.dumps(
                entry.xpath(".//div[@class='entry-labels']/span/text()").getall()
                , separators=("|", ":")
                )
        }
```

Comment: Im not a huge fan of them either +1

Comment: I assumed as much considering the lack of documentation in scrapy about it. I appreciate the explanation.